# How to prevent icon position from changing in input when invalid feedback occur?

Tags: html, css, input, icons

[image][image]

I was facing this problem when there is **invalid feedback** in the credential, it will cause the **icon to move away** from its original position. Hereby I attach my code with the relevant CSS. For Your information, I apply bootstrap & Bootstap icon in my design code.

```
<div class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left mb-3">
     <input type="text" class="form-control form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" id="username"  
     name="username" placeholder="Username">
     <div class="form-control-icon">
         <i class="bi bi-person"></i>
     </div>
    @error('username')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
    @enderror
</div>
```

**CSS Part**

```
.form-group[class*=has-icon-].has-icon-left .form-control-icon{left:0}
.invalid-feedback{display:none;width:100%;margin-top:.25rem;font-size:80%;color:#dc3545}
.form-group{margin-bottom:.7rem}
.position-relative{position:relative!important}
.form-control {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      padding: 12px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-radius: 2.5px;
      font-size: 14px;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
           appearance: none;
      margin-bottom: 24px;
    }
.form-group[class*=has-icon-].has-icon-left .form-control-icon{left:0}.
```

Comment: .form-group[class*=has-icon-].has-icon-left .form-control-icon{    position: absolute;left:0px;top:0px}

Comment: I managed to fixed it right now by having `{ position: absolute;left:0px;top:0px}` Thank You!!

Comment: Welcome can you up vote comment.

Comment: alright currently my reputation is not yet over 15 so I can't vote up or maybe do you wan to put your answer in the answer column instead of comment?

Comment: I have added Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may Help You!!!

```
.form-group[class*=has-icon-].has-icon-left .form-control-icon{ position: absolute;left:0px;top:0px}
```